# boost random sample like python random.sample

Tags: c++, python, boost, random

I am trying to use C++ to mimic python

```
random.sample(a_set, n_samples)
```

C++ function like

```
set<string> sample(set<string> input, int n_samples)
```

Before writing my own, is there any library doing this? I have boost 1.46 on my computer.

Comment: If I get it right, you need a function, that generates you `n_samples` unique random numbers, right?

Comment: @KirilKirov Choose `n_samples` unique elements from the population of `a_set`.

Answer (score 2):

Since C++17 there is [std::sample](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample):

```
std::sample(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(out),
            n_samples, std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});
```

*The original answer follows. I leave it here for reference.*

---

The [SGI's implementation of the STL](https://web.archive.org/web/20171211162332/https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html) has [`random_sample`](https://web.archive.org/web/20171116104828/http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/random_sample.html) and [`random_sample_n`](https://web.archive.org/web/20171116105038/http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/random_sample_n.html) functions:

```
template <class InputIterator, class RandomAccessIterator>
Random AccessIterator random_sample(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                                    RandomAccessIterator ofirst,
                                    RandomAccessIterator olast) 

template <class ForwardIterator, class OutputIterator, class Distance>
OutputIterator random_sample_n(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
                               OutputIterator out, Distance n)
```

`random_sample_n` randomly copies a sample of the elements from the range `[first, last)` into the range `[out, out + n)`. Each element in the input range appears at most once in the output range and samples are chosen with uniform probability.

Unfortunately

> Matt Austern proposed several additional algorithms (mostly taken from SGI's original STL implementation for the standard library). Among these were
>   `random_sample` and `random_sample_n`

*<sup>(from [N3925](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3925.pdf))</sup>*

but

> After WG21 consideration at the Sophia-Antipolis meeting, Austern updated the proposal, producing [N2666]. Among other changes, he withdrew the  sampling algorithms because "The LWG was concerned that they might not be well enough understood for standardization... It may be appropriate to propose those algorithms for TR2". LWG subsequently achieved a solid
>   consensus (10-1, 2 abs.) in support of having these algorithms in a future Technical Report (now termed a Technical Specification).

A version of the `random_sample_n` algorithm has made it to the Library Fundamentals TS and is called [`std::experimental::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/sample), the latest iteration of the proposal [N3925](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3925.pdf) was adopted in 2014-02 but remains not yet part of the standard (probably in C++17).

In addition to the reservoir sampling algorithm, you can take a look to the well-known *algorithms S* ("**selection sampling technique**") elucidated by Donald Knuth in The Art of Computer Programming - Volume 2 - §3.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are looking to solve is called [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). I tried googling for "reservoir sampling c++ implementation". Google auto-completes the query for me, but a cursory glance through the results doesn't turn up an actual library.

The algorithm is very simple and kind of fun to learn and write up yourself, so that's what I would recommend.